# executing command line, hide return and save it

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I run this below I am shown the return straight away on screen

```
   #!/usr/bin/python3    
    import os    
    myVar = os.system('echo, Hello')
```

> ```
>  Hello
> ```

How do I stop it being shown but save the result for use later? 
I expected to be able to print the results using `print (("%s")% myVar)` but that just returns `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use check_output from subprocess like this:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['echo', 'Hello'], shell=True)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use subprocess module for this

```
import subprocess

yourProc = subprocess.Popen("echo, Hello", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = yourProc.communicate()
print(stdout)
```